# Rails session getting reset

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session, csrf-protection

I am having a strange problem. I recently detected that a text field that was posted via AJAX was giving error. Upon investigation, I found out that the session gets reset for this POST AJAX request. I thought must be csrf issue. I checked the token and it is being passed correctly like in the layout file:

```
  <%= javascript_tag "var AUTH_TOKEN = #{form_authenticity_token.inspect};" if protect_against_forgery? -%>
```

And my AJAX request looks like this:

```
 <script type="tex/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#post_msg").click(function(){
                            var update = $("#msg").val();
                            var authenticity_token = AUTH_TOKEN;
                            $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "/messages.js",
                                    data: "msg[text]="+escape(msg) + "&_csrf_token="+encodeURIComponent(authenticity_token),
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function(msg){
                                      // Code to append the msg to DOM
                                    )
```

But in the debugger, I notice that the csrf token is different from the one already in the hash. I am unable to comprehend all this. Any clues what might be the reason for all this?

Comment: Are you using page caching?  If so, you're probably caching the form with one CSRF token, and then serving it up again to another user later.

Answer (score 0):

In a working Rails 3 app of mine, the token name is `authenticity_token` and the actual token itself is not encoded before POSTing.